# 2D plot with colours, according to values, on the X-Y plane

Tags: matlab, colors, plot

I have arbitrary points (X,Y) to which, has two corresponding eigenvalues.

I have decided to categorize the eigenvalues in to three categories, namely:

1. Both > 0
2. Both < 0
3. Either one = 0
4. 1 eigenvalue > 0 , 2nd eigenvalue < 0

I would like to plot it out, color coding each point (X,Y), on the X-Y plane with a different colour.

I have used imagesc but it does not show the X-Y plane.

Here is a sketch of what I'm trying to get, where the colour coding indicates the scenerio of the eigenvalue obtained for that particular (X,Y).

[image: Sketch]

p.s. Pardon me, there should be 1 more case, i.e. 1 eigenvalue > 0 , 2nd eigenvalue < 0

Could someone direct me to where I can read up more about this?

Edit: Here is my code.

***vecStor*** is a 2 x *n* matrix storing the eigenvalue in each corresponding row.

```
%e.g     vecStor = [ 1 2 3 ; 4 5 6] 
%eigenvalues 1 and 4 corresponds to (X1,Y1)
%eigenvalues 2 and 5 corresponds to (X2,Y2)
```

Next I assigned a value to each "case"
and where *l* is the counter for the for loop to run through the ***vecStor***

```
if (vecStor(1,l) < 0 && vecStor(2,l) < 0)
fprintf('Double Neg\n')
colourStore(l,1) = -3;

else if (vecStor(1,l) > 0 && vecStor(2,l) > 0)
fprintf('Double Pos\n')
colourStore(l,1) = +3;

else if (vecStor(1,l) > 0 && vecStor(2,l) < 0)
fprintf('One Pos One Neg!\n')
colourStore(l,1) = -1;

else if (vecStor(1,l) == 0 || vecStor(2,l)  == 0)
fprintf('One Zero!\n')
colourStore(l,1) = +1;
```

Finally I plot it out

```
img=colourStore';
imagesc(img);
axis image;
```

Comment: Can you add some code showing how you tried `imagesc`? Also show the format of your data

Comment: I think that you have misinterpreted `image`. The image data is a NxMx3 matrix such that the two first indices indicates the xy-location and the third index is the RGB colors. So this means that `img(1,1,1)` would be the red intensity in point (1,1), `img(2,1,2)` the green intensity in point (2,1), `img(34,13,1)` would be the red intensity in point (34,13) and so on. And sorry for all the repetitions. I usually finds 3D matrices hard to interpret, so more examples will help see the pattern better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input data (`vecStore`) should be 3 dimensional vector with dimensions `NxMx2`, where `N` is the number of rows (or Y height), `M` is the number of columns (or X width) and the third dimension has size 2 (for two eigenvalues per X/Y value). Let's create a random matrix representing your eigenvalues:

```
numRows = 10;
numColumns = 10;
vecStor = randn(numRows,numColumns,2);
```

Then you check for the conditions of every element in the matrix, similar to what you did in your code snippet. Loop through all rows and columns and create a two-dimensional color-map that contains four distinct values according to the eigenvalue properties:

```
colourStore = zeros(numRows,numColumns);
for r = 1:size(vecStor, 1)
    for c = 1:size(vecStor, 2)
        if (vecStor(r,c,1) < 0 && vecStor(r,c,2) < 0)
            % Double Neg
            colourStore(r,c) = -3;            
        elseif (vecStor(r,c,1) > 0 && vecStor(r,c,2) > 0)
            % Double Pos
            colourStore(r,c) = +3;            
        elseif (vecStor(r,c,1) > 0 && vecStor(r,c,2) < 0)
            % First Pos, Second Neg
            colourStore(r,c) = -1;            
        elseif (vecStor(r,c,1) == 0 || vecStor(r,c,2)  == 0)
            % One Zero
            colourStore(r,c) = +1;
        end
    end
end
```

Finally, plot `colourStore` as color image:

```
imagesc(colourStore);
```

Example output:

[image: Eigenvalues color plot]

### Edit

Here's a way to do the categorization without loops, using logical indexing:

```
colourStore(vecStor(:,:,1) < 0 & vecStor(:,:,2) < 0 ) = -3;
colourStore(vecStor(:,:,1) > 0 & vecStor(:,:,2) > 0) = 3;
colourStore(vecStor(:,:,1) > 0 & vecStor(:,:,2) < 0) = -1;
colourStore(vecStor(:,:,1) == 0 | vecStor(:,:,2) == 0) = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. I suppose its one way of approaching this problem. But I now realize I'll be dealing with coordinates of (X,Y), from the range of 0 to 1 (i.e. 0.1,0.2). This makes it difficult to access elements of the various vectors. I suppose I can scale vecStor. But eventually when I plot colourStore, this gives a headache. So I'm looking into that. But I am seeing how this imagesc works now after your example. Thanks. Finally, more trivially, in your example output, the Y-axis begins from the top, instead of from the same bottom-left corner of the figure where the X-axis begins